# Object or Boolean how to declare type in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Came across this type declaration problem in React.

```
interface MessageCardProps {
  message: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    attachments: string[];
    interest_count: number;
  };
}

const MessageCard: FC<MessageCardProps> = ({
  message: { id, title, content, attachments, interest_count },
}) => {
  // ERROR: Type 'string | false' is not assignable to type 'boolean | { url: string; }'.
  const image: { url: string } | boolean =
    attachments.length > 0 ? attachments[0] : false;

  return (
    {/* Property 'url' does not exist on type 'true | { url: string; }'.*/}
    {image && <img className={style.img} src={image.url} alt="timeline" />}
  );
};

export default MessageCard;
```

What is the right way to declare the type of `const image`? It can either be an object with the URL property or a boolean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first issue is that `attachments[0]` will return a string, not an object with an `url` property. So you can use the type `string | boolean`. Is there a specific reason why you want to wrap it in an object?

If you use `string | boolean`, you can do `src={image}`

**Edit:**

You could even improve on this even more by just not using boolean at all, and using the fact that `null` is a falsy value. Then you can do this.

```
const image: string = attachments.length > 0 ? attachments[0] : null;

return (
  {image && <img className={style.img} src={image} alt="timeline" />}
);
```

**Edit 2:**

As it turns out, the `attachments` property in `MessageCardProps` should not be an array of strings, but an array of objects with a property called "URL". So this is what it should look like:

```
interface MessageCardProps {
  message: {
    id: string;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    attachments: {URL: string}[];
    interest_count: number;
  };
}
```

Now, to get the first image, you can do this:

```
const image: string = attachments.length > 0 ? attachments[0].URL : null;
```

Comment: Still receiving: ```Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.```. 

Attachments contain the following information:
```
"attachments": [
      {
        "URL": "URL",
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @MapMyMind Then `attachments` in `MessageCardProps` has the wrong type definition. It should say `attachments: {URL: string}[]`. Then you can use `attachments.length > 0 ? attachments[0].URL : null`

Comment: Also, are you using strictNullChecks? Then image needs to be either string or null, like this `const image: string | null = ...`

Comment: That is right, the declaration in the interface is wrong. Changed ```attachments: string[]``` to ```attachments: {URL: string}[];```. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want the image to be set only if attachments[0] is set ?

if yes, I would type this way. (there are quickest and more simple way to do it , but this code the usage of union of types and typeof):

```
const attachments:Array<string> = ["/test"]

interface IImage {url:string | boolean }
const image : IImage  = attachments.length > 0 ? {url:attachments[0]} : {url:false}}

return(

        {image && typeof image.url==='string' && image.url!=="" && (<p>I have a valid url</p>)}

)
```